# Jenkins pipeline log: strings are split and characters are surrounded with '****'

Tags: jenkins

I'm facing a problem with Jenkins jobs (pipeline) console output.
Each word is split and each character is surrounded with '****'
Example:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Prepare workspace)
[Pipeline] sh
****[****R****u****n****n****i****n****g**** ****s****h****e****l****l**** ****s****c****r****i****p****t****
```

From this point, all the log is formatted like this.
I cannot figure out the cause of this strange formatting...

Jenkins version: 2.60.2

Thanks for any suggestion

Pipeline looks like this:

```
node {
def credentialList = []
credentialList.add([$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'USER_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD'])

withCredentials(credentialList) {
  stage("Prepare workspace") {
      def pipScript = '''#!/bin/bash
          ...
          shell instructions
          ...
      '''
      sh pipScript
  }
}
```

}

Comment: The jenkins is running on a linux server.
After upgrading to version 2.85, the problem has disappeared. The jenkins is not mine and I cannot downgrade to the previous version to verify if there is a link with the jenkins version or the pipeline plugin version.  
Without any clue about the cause of the problem, I'm still interested to know if anyone has already met this behavior.

Comment: If a version upgrade fixed your problem , all is clear : **jenkins issue**.  Try to create an account and register your issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa